# uninitialized constant BikeShare (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to implement some simple testing in rspec for a gem I'm writing. When I comment out `describe BikeShare do` down to `end` and run the file, the file loads in and runs successfully. I'm sure it's something tiny I'm missing.

My test file is really simple and looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe BikeShare do

  it "should run" do
    # response = BikeShare.new
    # response.should_be present
  end

end
```

When run, I get the error `uninitialized constant BikeShare (NameError)` at line 3.

My `bikeshare.rb` file looks like this, fairly simple:

```
class BikeShare

  def initialize
    response = JSON.parse(open("http://bayareabikeshare.com/stations/json").read)
    @response = response["stationBeanList"]
  end

  def get_last_station
    @response.last["id"]
  end
end
```

My `Rakefile` looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup

Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks

require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |spec|
  # spec.libs << 'lib' << 'spec'
  spec.pattern = 'spec/*_spec.rb'
end

task :default => :spec
```

Comment: I don't use rspec so I could be wrong, but how does it know about your bike share class? you probably just need to require it.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Happy to give you credit if you want to write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests arent aware of BikeShare.

You need to require the file that defines your BikeShare class. I dont use rspec but I think that you normally set up your testing environment in `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: Either include bikeshare.rb in spec_helper.rb or in bikeshare.spec, common convention is to do it in spec_helper.